# Which interface for GETH is the most ideal to learn? How do they differ?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, console, command-line

In trying to learn Ethereum and its inner working, i came a crossed https://www.ethereum.org/cli .

It states...

"Geth and Eth are multipurpose command line tools that run a full Ethereum node. They offer multiple interfaces: the command line subcommands and options, a JSON-RPC server and an interactive console."

Seems like there would be 3 ways to communicate with GETH

- Command line subcommands and options
- JSON-RPC server
- Interactive console

Which interface is best to learn in order for full functionality? Do they all accomplish the same things but in different methods/languages?

Hopefully i can receive clarification on this.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://blog.b9lab.com/unpacking-the-ethereum-stack-for-developers-c1be1dc41c06

Answer (score 2):

They do not accomplish the same things. You will need the 3 interfaces.

*Command line* and options is how you are going to run GETH. *Interactive console* is how you can send transactions, unlock account and communicate with the Ethereum blockchain.

Keep on with your learning and you will understand the difference here. Install GETH, learn how to start a private network, then try to connect to Rinkeby and then try to do some mining. You will improve your learning curve after a couple of hours trying new stuff using GETH.